# How to compute the amplitude of a Feynman diagram with a loop containing a fermion and a scalar?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, fermions, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I know that when we have a Feynman diagram with a fermion loop, we must take the trace and, by doing so, we *get rid of* the $\gamma$ matrices.

What if we have a diagram like the one in the picture below, which contains one fermion and one scalar particle in the loop?

[image]

Should we also take the trace? Since the fermion propagator is given by $$i \frac{{\not p + m}}{p^2 - m^2 + i \varepsilon}$$ and the trace of a $\gamma$ matrix is equal to $0$, then, if we take the trace, the term proportional to $\not p$ will vanish and therefore the diagram will be proportional to the mass of the fermion. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi @jmaguire. This is not a fermion loop I think.

Comment: Hi @schris38. I know this is not a fermion loop. But one of the internal particles in this loop is a fermion.

Comment: So, why should you take the trace, upon computing matrix elements? This only happens in closed fermion loops

Comment: @schris38, so you get an amplitude which is a matrix? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can not get an amplitude that has Lorentz, Dirac or any other free indices. However, here you do not have a full amplitude. You merely have the expression for the progagator, which is afterall going to be connected to other parts of the diagram. This does not mean that you will get a trace of the $\gamma$ matrix, it only means that your $\gamma$ matrix is going to be multiplied with some other matrices and columnts/rows

Comment: @schris38, so how do you compute the correction to the mass of the fermion from a diagram like this?

Comment: This procedure is very long. I can only refer you to some QFT textbooks (i.e. Srednicki or Peskin)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't take a trace here

[image]

Comment: Please use MathJax, rather than images, for displaying mathematical material.  (In this case, it also doesn't help that it looks like the bottom of the image has been cut off.